# RedirectToAction MVC5 doesn't work

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new in Asp.Net MVC, so sorry if it looks trivial.

I'm following this tutorial: http://techbrij.com/custom-roleprovider-authorization-asp-net-mvc

I have a problem with `RedirectToAction` method, I'm calling it after my login action like that:

```
        // POST: /Account/Login
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public  ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                using (AferSuiviDBEntities objContext = new AferSuiviDBEntities())
                {
                    var objUser = objContext.People.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CompanyMail == model.Email && x.CompanyPassword == model.Password);
                    if (objUser == null)
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("LogOnError", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Email, model.RememberMe);
                        Session["MyMenu"] = null;
                        if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
                           && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
                        {
                            return Redirect(returnUrl);
                        }
                        else
                        {

                            return RedirectToAction("RedirectToDefault");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }
```

I wrote a `RedirectToDefault` method that checks the logged user and show the according page :

```
        public ActionResult RedirectToDefault()
        {

            String[] roles = Roles.GetRolesForUser();
            if (roles.Contains("Administrator"))
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else if (roles.Contains("Engineer"))
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Engineer");
            }
            else if (roles.Contains("PublicUser"))
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "PublicUser");
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }
```

My routeConfigfile is the following:

```
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

The problem is that when I'm setting the credentials and then clicking on the "login" Button, it's going from this url :

**http://localhost:3343/Account/Login**

to this one :

**http://localhost:3343/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FAccount%2FRedirectToDefault**

But the login page is still shown ! can anyone explain for me why please ??

PS: I put a breakpoint in the RedirectToDefault Method, and I saw that it's not entering inside!

**UPDATE**

My login view:

```
@model LoginViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Log in";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <section id="loginForm">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                <h4>Use a local account to log in.</h4>
                <hr />
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <input type="submit" value="Log in" class="btn btn-default" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <p>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Register as a new user", "Register")
                </p>
                @* Enable this once you have account confirmation enabled for password reset functionality
                    <p>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Forgot your password?", "ForgotPassword")
                    </p>*@
            }
        </section>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <section id="socialLoginForm">
            @Html.Partial("_ExternalLoginsListPartial", new ExternalLoginListViewModel { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl })
        </section>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

Here's an image of my code, it shows that the process is really going to my RedirectToAction Method :

[image]

But when clicking on F11 it's not going inside my "RedirectToDefault" Method, it finish, but it just refresh my first login view.

Comment: What is the `action` attribute of the `<form>` tag in the `Login` view?

Comment: Where is your method `RedirectToDefault` - in the same controller? 
If you put a breakpoint on line `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Email, model.RememberMe)`, is the `RedirectToDefault` even being called?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I update the post for you

Comment: No, I meant what is the actual html generated for the `<form>` tag

Comment: @OllieP yes it does ! it goes until the  return RedirectToAction("RedirectToDefault"); instruction, but when I'm clicking on F11 button, it's not enternig inside the Method RedirectToDefault !!

Comment: @StephenMuecke how to get it ?! I put all my login view!

Comment: Open the page, the view the page source (or inspect the element in your browser console)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, before clicking on login button :

<form action="/" class="form-horizontal" method="post" role="form">

After clicking on login Button: 

<form action="/?ReturnUrl=%2FAccount%2FRedirectToDefault" class="form-horizontal" method="post" role="form">

Comment: @JohnH what to do then ?? it was said like that in the tutorial ! and it's for a reason ! how to solve it ?

Comment: There is nothing in the code you have shown which is setting the value of `returnUrl`. Is the `RedirectToDefault` method in the `AccountController`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes it is ! for returnUrl, the first time is empty, but when I click on login a second time, it contains the url. but the first click is taking me to return RedirectToAction("RedirectToDefault"); after that it's doing noothing...

Comment: Strange. Do you have any `[Authorize]` attribute on the `RedirectToDefault()` method that may be preventing it from being hit?

Comment: no nothing ! I did exactelly what was said in the tutorial and as I showed you here !

Comment: @Alvaro, Do you have an `[Authorize]` on the controller? Something is causing you to redirect back the the Loin page as soon as you try to redirect to `RedirectToDefault`. Try also putting `[AllowAnonymous]` on the `RedirectToDefault` method.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't calling your method. This line

```
                    else
                    {

                        return RedirectToAction("RedirectToDefault");
                    }
```

should be

```
                    else
                    {

                        return RedirectToDefault();
                    }
```

Comment: I've tried this, it goes inside the called method, and everything works, but the problem is that login credentials are not saved! therefore I have to use "RedirectToAction".
it's explained here:
http://techbrij.com/custom-roleprovider-authorization-asp-net-mvc

Comment: You should add that info to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your Login Get method should like this

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
{
    ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
    return View();
}
```

and Login Post method is same as you have coded.

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public  ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (AferSuiviDBEntities objContext = new AferSuiviDBEntities())
            {
                var objUser = objContext.People.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CompanyMail == model.Email && x.CompanyPassword == model.Password);
                if (objUser == null)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("LogOnError", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
                }
                else
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Email, model.RememberMe);
                    Session["MyMenu"] = null;
                    if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
                       && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
                    {
                        return Redirect(returnUrl);
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        return RedirectToAction("RedirectToDefault");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
}
```

and form tag like

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }))
    {   
        // html for login form
    }
```

Comment: return Redirect(returnUrl); this statement is execute that's why it is redirected to http://localhost:3343/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FAccount%2FRedirectToDefault. check what is the value of returnUrl.

Comment: what is the value of returnUrl, when u post form

Comment: it's null value, see the updated 2 in my post please

Comment: return RedirectToAction("ActionName", "ControllerName"); can u pls use this statement

Comment: u are posting form using ajax post?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73162/discussion-between-chirag-arvadia-and-alvaro).